# How to retrieve IEnumerable List within model rendered for view model back to controller upon post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a text file and when users upload the file, the controller action method parses that file using state machine and uses a generic list to store some values. I pass this back to the view in the form of an IEnumerable. Within my main view, based on this ienumerable list I render a partail view to iterate items and display labels and a textarea. Users could add their input in the text area. When the users hit the save button this ienumrable list from the partial view rendered is null. so please advice any solutions.

here is my main view

```
@model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntry
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

   @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {

<div id="inputTestExceptions" style="display: none;">
        <table class="grid" style="width: 450px; margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Exception String
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Comment
                    </th>
                </tr>             </thead>

            <tbody>
                @if (Model.TestExceptions != null)
                {
                    foreach (var p in Model.TestExceptions)
                    {
                        Html.RenderPartial("RunLogTestExceptionSummary", p);

                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
     }
```

partial view as follows:

```
@model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay
<tr>
    <td>
    @Model.TestException@
       </td>
        <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(Model.Comment, new { style = "width: 200px; height: 80px;" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Controller action

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(RunLogEntry runLogEntry, String ServiceRequest, string Hour, string Minute, string AMPM,
                                 string submit, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file, String AssayPerformanceIssues1, IEnumerable<RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay> models)
    {
```

}

The problem is test exceptions which contains exception string and comment is comming back null.

UPDATE

```
public class RunLogEntry
{
   SOME OTHER FIELDS

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay> TestExceptions { get; set; }
}



public class RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay
{
    public string TestException { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}



@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
         if (Model.TestExceptions != null)
           {
               if (Model.TestExceptions.Count() > 0)
               {
        <div class="bodyContent">
            <span class="leftContent">
                @Html.Label("Test Exceptions")
            </span><span class="rightContent"><span id="TestExceptionChildDialogLink" class="treeViewLink">
                Click here to View Test Exceptions</span>
                <br />
                <span id="TestExceptionDisplay"></span>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TestExceptions)
                @*<input id="ExceptionString" type="hidden" value="@Model.ExceptionString" />*@
            </span>
        </div>
               }
           }


   <div id="inputTestExceptions" style="display: none;">
        <table class="grid" style="width: 450px; margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Exception String
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Comment
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @if (Model.TestExceptions != null)
            {
                var index = 0;
                foreach (var p in Model.TestExceptions)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>@p.TestException
                        <input type="hidden" name="RunLogEntry.TestExceptions[@index].ExceptionString" value="@p.TestException" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name="RunLogEntry.TestExceptions[@index].Comment" style ="width: 200px; height: 80px;">@p.Comment</textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" name="RunLogEntry.TestExceptions[@index].Comment" value="@p.Comment" />
                    </td>
                    @* Html.RenderPartial("RunLogTestExceptionSummary", p);*@
                </tr>
                                                                                                 index++;
                }

            }
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To post a collection, you need to name the form elements in an array style. You'll also have to keep a counter so you can set the array index in the html element names/id's.

```
@{var index = 0;}
@foreach (var p in Model.TestExceptions) {
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Model.TestException@
     </td>
      <td>
          <textarea name="@Html.FieldNameFor(m => m.TestExceptions[@index].Comment" id="@Html.FieldIdFor(m => m.TestExceptions[@index].Comment" style ="width: 200px; height: 80px;">@p.Comment</textarea>
          <input type="hidden" name="@Html.FieldNameFor(m=> m.TestExceptions[@index].ExceptionString" id="@Html.FieldIdFor(m=> m.TestExceptions[@index].ExceptionString" value="@p.ExceptionString" />
      </td>
  </tr>
index++;
}
```

I don't know what your model looks like, but you mentioned an exception string, so I used a hidden form element to store the value of an "ExceptionString" property so that the model binding can pick up these values when you POST.

if your RunLogEntry class has other properties besides the TestExceptions collection, you can ensure it will bind correctly on POST by including form elements that will map to the RunLogEntry properties. For example, if you have RunLogEntry.Foo property, you'd put this somewhere outside the above loop:

```
<input type="hidden" name="RunLogEntry.Foo" value="@Model.Foo" />
```

Comment: This is a property within model RunLogEntry        public IEnumerable<RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay> TestExceptions { get; set; }

Comment: then there is this @model RunLog.Domain.Entities.RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay which has two properties i.e test exception string and comment string

Comment: in the main view im rendering the test exception display as a partial within a loop, it renders fine, just on post i cant see the values

Comment: I got rid of the partial view and rendered as you mentioned above, the testexception is still comming back as 0 for the count and so i cant get the invidiual test exceptions and comment.

Comment: Can you paste the code for the RunLogEntry class, and also for any classes it contains (including RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay )?

Comment: Hey there I just updated and posted the code for both these classes, on the post in controller, if i look within runlog entry model being posted, test exceptions: exceptionstring should be a list right because thats what i just rendered to the view, the users will not modify the exception string and only add any comment if they choose to add.

Comment: In the controller action, are any of RunLogEntry's other properties being bound?

Comment: Oh yes, all other properties are being rendered to the view and posted back to the controller correctly

Comment: Other errors:  You are assigning the .Comment property twice in the html form: once in the `<textarea>`, and once in the hidden input field. The hidden field was meant to be for the .TestException property. If you don't want to bind that for some reason, don't include the hidden field. I would keep the hidden field and have it bind to .TestException for now, just to keep things simple. Next, why do you have this code in there: Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.TestExceptions) ?

Comment: You should try to do one thing at a time. Try just posting back an IEnumerable<RunLogEntryTestExceptionDisplay> by itself, and having that bind on POST. Use scott hanselman's blog post about binding to lists/collections to help get that part right. Once you have this you should easily be able to put the IEnumerable<> back into the RunLogEntry object and have it bind as RunLogEntry.TestExceptions.

Comment: @if (Model.TestExceptions != null)
            {
                var index = 0;
                foreach (var p in Model.TestExceptions)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>@p.TestException
                        <input type="hidden" name="RunLogEntry.TestExceptions[@index].ExceptionString" value="@p.TestException" />
                    </td>
                   
                </tr>
                                                                                                         index++;
                }

            }

Comment: i am rendering the above in a loop, first td i display the value and the second td is its hidden value for the post.

Comment: You have redundant form fields. <textarea> and <input hidden> within your loop both have identical values for the name attribute. This probably confuses the model binder when you try to POST.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16981/discussion-between-giscard-biamby-and-user1475788)